Is there a meaningful difference between an async IIFE and a new Promise?
Consider the following assignments:
const promise1 = (async () => {
    await someAsyncFunction();
})();

const promise2 = new Promise(async resolve => {
    await someAsyncFunction();
    resolve();
});

Is there any meaningful difference between these two Promises (other than verbosity)?

@ITgoldman But either way, it gets called. I don't see why it matters exactly what does the calling. This is why I ask: as far as I can tell, the outcome of both is the same.

@mplungjan As it turns out, the banned AI is banned for a reason. It's not quite right here.

Worth investigating, yes, but not quite correct, as I said. It is true that promise1 rejects and promise2 doesn't, but both promise1 and promise2 cause unhandled promise rejection errors. Also worth noting that promise2 doesn't resolve either; it just gets stuck.

Why do you ask this, when you can just do const promise = someAsyncFunction(); and passing an async callback to the promise constructor is an antipattern?

@trincot In the example, yes, you could do const promise = someAsyncFunction(); but my actual code (which I can't share) is more complex. And I don't accept "xyz is an antipattern" as a legitimate argument without further reasoning.

the further reasoning includes: (1) the caller of the executor callback does not look at the returned value, and so the promise returned by the async function is ignored, let be that there would be any reaction to a fulfillment or rejection. (2) An async function is only really useful when it uses await, which means you have a promise to await, but then this is an example of the promise constructor antipattern.

Never pass an async function as the executor to new Promise!

@phuzi Not specifically.

@Bergi Thank you, I've gone ahead and self-closed this as a duplicate of that one, which answers the question satisfactorily by describing why promise2 is ill-conceived.

Consider the following definition of someAsyncFunction:
async function someAsyncFunction() {
    throw "Error in someAsyncFunction!";
}

In this case, both promise 1 and promise 2 cause an unhandled rejection error. But afterwards, the two promises are in different states. Promise 1 (defined using the async IIFE) has rejected with the reason "Error in someAsyncFunction!" but promise 2 is still pending. This behavior was confirmed in NodeJS and Firefox.

Put .catch(console.error) on each promise then. On promise1, you can handle the rejection with that, on promise2, everything is lost. Never pass an async function as the executor to new Promise!

They're basically the same, the IIFE is syntactic sugar for the 2nd version
